# A quick tool for inputting many special characters?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, special-characters

You might be thinking that I can use a special keyboard layout or alt codes. However, they don't provide enough characters. Unicode alt codes in the other hand require knowing every single Unicode code.

I want a quick method of entering many special characters. I am thinking of something along the lines of using a keyboard shortcut to open a window like this:

[image: [backspace]

The character set should be customizable.

Comment: assign a hot key to open a text editor on a unicode file, make the file read-only once you have the content right.

Comment: Which operating system? On Windows you have Character Map.

Comment: the charmap is not a quick method, as I have to transfer every single character (except for spaces, which are omitted in charmap) to the text box below, then copy to whatever I want it to. in the window picture above, whatever character is clicked on is immediately typed to the text box in focus, like the on-screen keyboard but with 1193 Unicode characters instead of keyboard keys.

Comment: Have you already used all key combinations of your existing keyboard so that you are asking for more?

Comment: US keyboard has 95 characters. Customizing the Alt Gr layer can only give twice as many, giving 190. Much less than 1193.